# How to read a value from an object - Unhandled Exception

Tags: flutter, dart

After days of useless attempts, I'm new with Flutter, I can only ask for help from those who know more than me

I need to **read the value of 'G'**

that I get from an await that executes a query to a database and returns an eventObject **object** composed of:

```
id:
object:
```

(see better in the figure)

[image]

having a futures that returns exactly

```
return new EventObject (
       id: ...,
       object: gruppiJsonParsing.gruppo);
```

and gruppiJsonParsing that returns an instance of the Gruppi class with:

```
final String utente;
final String G;
```

with:

`var groupName = eventObject.object;`

I only get:

```
Instance of 'Gruppi'
```

then, since as in figure 0 = ['Gruppi']

I would think I could write

```
Gruppi groupName = eventObject.object;
String groupUser = groupName.G;
```

But so I get instead

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List <Groups'' is not a subtype of type 'Gruppi'
```

Thanks for any precious suggestions

---

Aa required here the code of GruppiJsonParsing.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_client_php_backend/models/Gruppi.dart';

class GruppiJsonParsing {
  final String result;
  final String message;
  final List<Gruppi> gruppo;

  GruppiJsonParsing({this.result, this.message, this.gruppo});

  factory GruppiJsonParsing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GruppiJsonParsing(
        result: json['result'],
        message: json['message'],
        gruppo: parseGruppi(json['gruppo']));
  }

  static List<Gruppi> parseGruppi(json) {
    List<Gruppi> gruppiList = new List<Gruppi>();

    for (var log in json) {
      gruppiList.add(new Gruppi(G: log['G']));
    }
    return gruppiList;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      <String, dynamic>{'result': result, 'message': message, 'gruppo': gruppo};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you json string look like this

```
{"result":"success","message":"Query Successful","gruppo": 
 [{"utente":null,"G":"utente1"}]}
```

you can parse with

```
final eventObject = eventObjectFromJson(jsonString);
print('${eventObject.gruppo[0].g}');
```

related class

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final eventObject = eventObjectFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

EventObject eventObjectFromJson(String str) => EventObject.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventObjectToJson(EventObject data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EventObject {
    String result;
    String message;
    List<Gruppo> gruppo;

    EventObject({
        this.result,
        this.message,
        this.gruppo,
    });

    factory EventObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EventObject(
        result: json["result"] == null ? null : json["result"],
        message: json["message"] == null ? null : json["message"],
        gruppo: json["gruppo"] == null ? null : List<Gruppo>.from(json["gruppo"].map((x) => Gruppo.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "result": result == null ? null : result,
        "message": message == null ? null : message,
        "gruppo": gruppo == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(gruppo.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Gruppo {
    dynamic utente;
    String g;

    Gruppo({
        this.utente,
        this.g,
    });

    factory Gruppo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Gruppo(
        utente: json["utente"],
        g: json["G"] == null ? null : json["G"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "utente": utente,
        "G": g == null ? null : g,
    };
}
```

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final eventObject = eventObjectFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

EventObject eventObjectFromJson(String str) => EventObject.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventObjectToJson(EventObject data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EventObject {
  String result;
  String message;
  List<Gruppo> gruppo;

  EventObject({
    this.result,
    this.message,
    this.gruppo,
  });

  factory EventObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EventObject(
    result: json["result"] == null ? null : json["result"],
    message: json["message"] == null ? null : json["message"],
    gruppo: json["gruppo"] == null ? null : List<Gruppo>.from(json["gruppo"].map((x) => Gruppo.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "result": result == null ? null : result,
    "message": message == null ? null : message,
    "gruppo": gruppo == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(gruppo.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Gruppo {
  dynamic utente;
  String g;

  Gruppo({
    this.utente,
    this.g,
  });

  factory Gruppo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Gruppo(
    utente: json["utente"],
    g: json["G"] == null ? null : json["G"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "utente": utente,
    "G": g == null ? null : g,
  };
}


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String jsonString = '{"result":"success","message":"Query Successful","gruppo":[{"utente":null,"G":"utente1"}]}';

  void _incrementCounter() {
    final eventObject = eventObjectFromJson(jsonString);
    print('${eventObject.gruppo[0].g}');

    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Output

```
I/flutter (19854): utente1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions,
really my json looks like:
{"result":"success","message":"Query Successful","gruppo":[{"utente":null,"G":"utente1"}]}.
Anyway i hope to understand and use your code

Comment: I have updated my code to fit your new json string and provide full code and output result. you can check again.